# is it possible to delete the value of text box with css :focus

Tags: css

I have the following form

```
<form id="enter_email" method="post" action="">
        <input type="text" value="enter email" />
        <input type="image" src="images/buttons/join-now.png"  />
    </form>
```

I was wondering if I can delete the value that shows on the text box by just css :focus alone,

thanks

Comment: Mis-understood, good too see the buzzards are circling with their vote down talons out.

Comment: I made a codepen demo of search box with clear button. This is done completely in CSS 

http://codepen.io/shidhincr/pen/ICLBD

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No you have to use script for that.

```
<input id="txt1" type="text" value="test value" onfocus="this.value='';" />
```

Answer (score 2):

There are ways in CSS to [prepend/append content](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/beforeafter.html) to a certain element, but nothing for modifying attribute values. But, if you really want to make use of CSS for this, you can have text as a `background-image` to that input and just change the `background` on `:focus`.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot change data using CSS.  You would have to use JavaScript and assign the value of the element to an empty string.

Comment: There is no innerHTMl property for textbox

Comment: innerHTML is a JavaScript property.

Comment: You cannot set innerHTML for input type text

Comment: Input text have value, not innerHTML.